# Setting same properites POJO in java

Tags: java, copy, pojo

I have two POJO with same setter and getter now i want to copy all the bean value to another bean. What can be the best way to copy all the information of one POJO to another.?

Comment: objects of same class or different class??

Comment: Show us some code, so we can give you some examples of how to write your adapter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use  Apache BeanUtils ...

Answer (score 2):

That's the perfect situation to use a Java Bean mapper like [orika](http://code.google.com/p/orika/) or [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). They can automate this task pretty well and you can avoid a lot of code.

You can basically copy all properties of random classes to other classes if they have the correct getters and setters with just a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Implement deep copy here. It will be best as all sub POJO's inside POJO will also be copied and there will be no loss.

```
public CloneExample deepCopy() {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
            oos.writeObject(this);

            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
            return (CloneExample) ois.readObject();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return null;
        }
```